# Is it okay to use nested classes as pure data sets, kind of like other languages 'Structs'?

Tags: java, struct, inner-classes

As the title says, is it okay to use a very trivial nested class just as a data holder, to act like a Struct existent in other programming languages?

For example, imagine that I need a method to return more than one value, is it okay to use this very simple nested class for this purpose? Or is it a bad practice?

As an example, imagine a scenario where you have to draw a shape using absolute coordinates (left, top, right, bottom) and what to retrieve the x and y coordinates clicked on a screen, but instead of starting to draw the shape at those coordinates, we need to offset them to draw the shape in the center of those coords, like this example demonstrate:

```java
public class DrawSquare {

    private class Positions {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }


    //* These classes may not exist in java.
    //* They're here just to exemplify functionality.
    private Rectangle mSquare;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Screen mScreen;

    private final int SIDE_LENGTH;

    public DrawSquare(int sideLength) {
        SIDE_LENGTH = sideLength;
        mSquare = new Rectangle();
    }

    //* Creates a square where the screen was clicked.
    public void createSquare() {
        Positions pos = processCoords(
                mScreen.getClickedX(),
                mScreen.getClickedY());

        //* Because the coords were processed, this rectangle
        //* will be created in the center of the clicked coords.
        mSquare.set(pos.left, pos.top, pos.right, pos.bottom);
        mPaint.draw(mSquare, mScreen);
    }


    //* Moves the square
    public void moveSquare() {
        Positions pos = processCoords(
                mScreen.getClickedX(),
                mScreen.getClickedY());

        //* Because the coords were processed, this rectangle
        //* will be moved to the center of the clicked coords.
        mPaint.animate(mSquare, mScreen)
                .moveTo(pos.left, pos.top, pos.right, pos.bottom)
                .setDuration(500)
                .start();
    }

    //* offset the coords to get a centered square
    private Positions processCoords(int x, int y) {
        Positions pos = new Positions();
        int halfLength = SIDE_LENGTH / 2;

        pos.left = x - halfLength;
        pos.top = y - halfLength;
        pos.right = x + halfLength;
        pos.bottom = y + halfLength;

        return pos;
    }

}
```

Those are just made up object types to exemplify the scenario I stated above.

Is that a good use case of a nested class?

Comment: [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: Use a static nested class.

Comment: Data encapsulation is frequently valuable. In a minority of cases, sometimes simplicity is more valuable. [Java records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359), introduced in Java 14, explicitly support what you seek.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn what if I have multiple shapes being drawn and moved concurrently? Doesn't static break that?

Comment: if you use `static class Positions {...}` it will not retain a reference to your enclosing object, which you should not need.

Answer (score 1):

That approach is almost fine, with a small nitpick:

Use a static nested class instead of an inner class:

```
public class DrawSquare {

    private static class Positions {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }
```

The difference is that a static nested class does not need a reference to a DrawSquare.

---

In Java 14, records are a preview feature.
One of the uses for them are exactly what you are doing there:

```
public class DrawSquare {

    private record Positions(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {}
```

Records are immutable, so you would have to change your creation a bit:

```
private Positions processCoords(int x, int y) {
    int halfLength = SIDE_LENGTH / 2;

    int left = x - halfLength;
    int top = y - halfLength;
    int right = x + halfLength;
    int bottom = y + halfLength;

    return new Positions(left, top, right, bottom);
}
```

A record will automatically create a constructor, accessors (`.left()`...) and overload `.equals(Object other)`, `.hashCode()` and `.toString()` for you.

But until this feature is in standard Java (without preview), your approach is fine.

Comment: doesn't making the class static generate concurrency problems?

Comment: No, a static nested class just doesn't hold a reference to it's enclosing class. It does not matter much in your current context, but it matters when you use an inner class for with a longer life cycle than it's enclosing scope (think callbacks).